# What are the differences between all the locations Java is installed on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos

There are several different Java executables on my Mac:

```
/usr/bin/java (symlink to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java)
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Most of them are Java 13, except for `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` is java 8. `which java` in the command line gives you `/usr/bin/java`, while double-clicking a jar file opens `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

**What's the difference between each of these locations, and what's the reason that each one exists?**

Comment: This question is not directly related to programming, thus off-topic. From what I see, I suspect at least `/usr/bin/java` to be a symlink. I would not be surprised if `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java` is a symlink aswell. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java ` seems to be the actual installation location. As to `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: /usr/bin/java is the only symlink.

Comment: Also, it's on topic because it's about [a software tool commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: the `Internet Plug-Ins` folder is for Safari, and it contains Java8 because that is the only supported version which runs applets:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet

> Java applets were deprecated since Java 9 in 2017 and removed from Java SE 11 (18.9), released in September 2018

plus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

> Java 11 is a currently supported long-term support (LTS) version ("Oracle Customers will receive Oracle Premier Support"); Oracle released for the "legacy" Java 8 LTS the last free "public update" in January 2019 for commercial use, while it will otherwise still support Java 8 with public updates for personal use up to at least December 2020.[3] Java 10 is the previously supported rapid release version. Java 10 support ended on the same date that support for Java 11 began, in September 2018. Java 7 is no longer publicly supported, and Java 9 has stopped receiving updates since Java 9 was a short-term rapid release version that has been superseded by Java 10 and now Java 11.

So applet support was there in Java9 and Java10, just those versions do not exist any more, while Java8 does.

You have Java13 because that is the current version otherwise. As one location says `jdk-13.0.1.jdk`, that should be a JDK. The strange "frameworks" thing with `A/Commands/java` does not seem like a "real" thing, Java runs from `bin` and `lib` folders on all platforms, even on Windows where such folders have no "tradition" at all. Those command things may rather be stubs/wrappers referring to the actual JDK. But I am typing on a tablet now, so I can't actually check.